# How to solve Unexpected token p in JSON at position 3 using angular2 or typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

[image]
When i go to save the survey content after editing, i get this error,

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 3
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Please anyone help me to solve this issue, I am hereby pasting my codes, please help.

ts code:

```
   Surveypost = () => {
    let token = this.auth.getAccessTokenId();
    console.log(token)
    let currentUser = this.auth.getCurrentUserData();
    console.log(this.editor.text)
    console.log(this.survey_val)
    // let survey_json = JSON.parse(this.editor.text);
    let survey_json:any;
   try{
   survey_json = JSON.parse(this.editor.text);
} catch(e) {
    /*Handle the error scenario here*/
}
    let survey_data = {
      "value": survey_json,
    };
    console.log(survey_data)
    this.AdminAPI
      .createandSet(survey_data, token)
      .subscribe(
        survey => {
           console.log(survey)
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        }

      );
  }
```

I am getting the consoled output till, `console.log(this.editor.text)`, then error comes.

The consoled output of  console.log(this.editor.text) starts like this,

```
{
 pages: [
  {
   name: "page1",
   elements: [
    {
     type: "radiogroup",
     name: "price",
     title: "How long have you been a customer at {companyname}?",
     isRequired: true,
     choices: [
      {
       value: "less",
       text: "0 - 3 months."
      },
      {
       value: "medium",
       text: "3 - 12 months."
      },
      {
       value: "High",
       text: "12 + months."
      }
     ]
```

Comment: what is the value of `console.log(this.editor.text)`

Comment: i get the json data over there

Comment: the data is not a json that what the error says

Comment: add console.log(this.editor.text) before calling JSON.parse and see what's inside the text. it should be a valid JSON text.

Comment: how to solve that issue please help

Comment: Reminder: When you want to parse text (from a 3rd party source) to JSON, you can wrap the line with a try-catch to handle the side-effects and to avoid propagating the error to unwanted areas
`try{JSON.parse("{p")}catch(e){/*Handle the expected bad JSON scenario here*/}`

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda: where should i put that line, please tel

Comment: @Bhrungarajni Please see my answer

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda I updated my question with my code, and got this error

Answer (score 1):

`this.editor.text` contains an invalid JSON. 
When trying to parse that invalid JSON the error occurs. So in short terms, the following line is the one that crash: `let survey_json = JSON.parse(this.editor.text);`

Grab the output from the `console.log(this.editor.text)`, run it trough a JSON validator/formatter like: 
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
And then you should be able to easily see why the error occurs, and why the program is not able to parse the JSON

**EDIT FROM WHEN JSON HAS BEEN ADDED**

AS you can see from the link mentioned above, the JSON is not valid, and that is the reason for the error message on the line: `let survey_json = JSON.parse(this.editor.text);`.
For instance a basic JSON should have the following structure:

```
{
 "key" : "value",
 "key2" : "value2"
}
```

You are also not ending the JSON correctly. I've formatted the JSON to a valid JSON here:

```
{  
"pages":[  
  {  
     "name":"page1",
     "elements":[  
        {  
           "type":"radiogroup",
           "name":"price",
           "title":"How long have you been a customer at {companyname}?",
           "isRequired":true,
           "choices":[  
              {  
                 "value":"less",
                 "text":"0 - 3 months."
              },
              {  
                 "value":"medium",
                 "text":"3 - 12 months."
              },
              {  
                 "value":"High",
                 "text":"12 + months."
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: i tried with link you gave, i will update what i got in the question, please help

Comment: Updated comment

Comment: the data is coming from backend, is there anyway to change in the code i had written?

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to parse some text sent from a 3rd party source, it is a good idea to wrap the parse logic with a try catch block. 
**But do remember that this should be done only after fixing the trivial bugs in the remote source(that is, if you have access, of course).**

replace,

```
let survey_json = JSON.parse(this.editor.text);
```

with,

```
let survey_json;
try{
   survey_json = JSON.parse(this.editor.text);
} catch(e) {
    /*Handle the error scenario here*/
    /*Lets assign an empty object(or possibly a default value) instead*/
   survey_json = {};
}
```

Comment: i added the code, i got. {"error":{"statusCode":422,"name":"ValidationError","message":"The `Survey` instance is not valid. Details: `value` can't be blank (value: undefined).","details":{"context":"Survey","codes":{"value":["presence"]},"messages":{"value":["can't be blank"]}},"stack":"ValidationError: The `Survey` instance is not valid. Details: `value` can't be blank (value: undefined).\n

Comment: This error is related to you application. When the code is unable to parse the data, you need a fallback path. For instance, you can assign an empty json object when an error occurs. I will edit the answer

Comment: Thanks, but here once the data is edited it must get saved, instaed i am getting the before data, instaed of updated data